# Latex indentation

Tags: indentation, parindent

I'm writing an article in LaTeX and in most cases, I do not want to have space at the beginning of the paragraph. Thus, I used the `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` command in the preamble.

However, there are some paragraphs, where I would like to have normal indentation. Is there a command that I could use in those cases?

(I'm looking for "reverse default mode". Normally, each paragraph (except the ones directly after `\(subsub)section`) has indentation and there is the `\noindent` command, which cancels the indentation. I would like to write an article without indentation and have a command (something similar to `\noindent`) that I could use in those rare cases where I need indentation.)

Comment: `\noindent`  is not used to suppress indentation after a section heading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a macro `\doindent` which creates an indentation as you wish:

```
\parindent=0pt  % all paragraphs are without indentation
\def\doindent{\hskip 2em\relax} % \doindent does indentation 2em
```